# Usage of photogenic

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Which is the correct way of using the word "Photogenic"

> 1. I look more photogenic with these glasses.
> 2. These glasses provide me a photogenic look.
> 3. These glasses make me look more photogenic.
> 4. These glasses make me a photogenic person.

I was just describing a pair of glasses I last purchased. So I had to choose any one of the above four sentences. The complete description that I used is as follows: I purchased red glasses on my last visit. Those glasses provided me a photogenic look. I think so because most of my photos taken during my visit in which I was wearing those glasses look far better than my other photos.

So, I know what the word means. I just need to know how to use it so it sounds natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **first** and **fourth** options sound most natural (regarding the use of *photogenic*), but overall, each of those sentences have a minor issue..

> I look more photogenic with these glasses.

Though this is purely personal preference, I would suggest including *on* at the end of this sentence, since the the act of being photogenic only happens when wearing the glasses (the converse could also be argued though). *I look more photogenic with these sunglasses **on**.*

> These glasses make me look more photogenic.

This statement seems slightly redundant by using *look*, since *photogenic* already addresses that someone's physical appearance is being considered (and thus, the act of "looking" a certain way is implied). *These glasses make me more photogenic.*

> These glasses provide me a photogenic look.

This statement is slightly off, and would sound better (but still not entirely idiomatic) if structured this way: *These glasses provide me **with** a photogenic look*.

> These glasses make me a photogenic person.

This statement doesn't sit well with me because it's too explicit due to the use of *person*. The individual is talking about themselves, so of course *person* is implied. Instead, I would perhaps change it to: *These glasses make me photogenic.*

**Note**: Since the second and fourth sentences are so similiar (in their corrected forms), the second statement is also acceptable.

Comment: I think the second one sounds most natural, with your recommended variant a good option: ***These glasses make me more photogenic.*** Also, I don't see the need to add the word _on_ after _I look more photogenic with these glasses_ – I think it sounds just fine without the _on_ tacked on at the end.

Comment: @J.R. Yeah, including *on* is personal preference, I suppose. Maybe if there was more emphasis on *these*, then I wouldn't think to add *on*.

Comment: @Charles I think the *on* is strongly implied.  Merely carrying or owning glasses wouldn't make one more photogenic :)

Comment: @Charles In the sentence "I look more photogenic with these glasses.", look and photogenic are redundant. Can we consider following  as a better form of this sentence: "I am made more photogenic by these  glasses."

Comment: @abhijeetpathak For that sentence, although both *look* and *photogenic*  are used, I don't think that the usage of *look* is redundant.. The reason because, if you remove *look* then it "breaks" the sentence: "*I more photogenic with these glasses*".To fix this, the sentence should read, "*I **am** more photogenic with these sunglasses*". With the other sentence though, the one that I *did* mention as slightly redundant, *look* can be removed without breaking the sentence.